# What's the Piechart about in the Character Panel of Cyber City Oedo 808?

Tags: cyber-city-oedo-808

In the intro of Cyber City Oedo 808 we get a character panel for each of the three main characters, depicting their profile, ie main stats etc. What does the pie chart indicate? What's it about? I can't make out the words exactly. Seems to me like "NEGRIDE", "MONGOLIDE". My guess is it is related to the origin (as in "Caucasian"), but I don't understand it, not sure. Check out the image to see what I'm talking about.

If anybody knows kindly share.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's their origin/race.**

The labels on the pie chart are:

> - [Mongolide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mongolide) (Mongoloid)
> - [Europide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/europide) (Caucasian)
> - [Negride](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negride) (Negroid)

which are actually in German.

The respective kanji is:

> [人種](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BA%BA%E7%A8%AE) (race):
>
> - [黄色](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%BB%84%E8%89%B2%E4%BA%BA%E7%A8%AE)系 (Mongoloid)
> - [白色](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%99%BD%E8%89%B2%E4%BA%BA%E7%A8%AE)系 (Caucasian)
> - [黒色](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%BB%92%E8%89%B2%E4%BA%BA%E7%A8%AE)系 (Negroid)
> - [その他](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%96) (others)

Comment: So Mongolide, Europide are actual english words?

Comment: @Nikos updated the answer; they are German words.